# if statement in obj-c expected expression error

Tags: objective-c, xcode8

A simple question from a newbie in coding using obj-c...
Look at this code:

```
**int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    // insert code here...
    //NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

    int a,b;

    a = 5;
    b = 6;
    if (a ==b) NSLog(@ "a is equal to b");
    if (a !=b)  NSLog(@ " a is not equal to b" );
    if (a > b)  NSLog(@ " a is greater that b");
    if ( a < b)  NSLog(@ " a is less than b");
    if ( a >= b)  NSLog(@ " a is greater of equal to b");
    if (a <= b) NSLog(@ " a is less or equal to b");
    if (!(a == b)) NSLog(@ " a is not (Equal to b)");
    if ((a == b)  || ( a =-- b )) NSLog(@ " a is equal to be, or a is equal to -- b");
    if ((a <= b) && (a < ++b)) NSLog(@ " a is less than or equal to b, and a is less than ++b");
    if (a == b) NSLog(@" a is equal to b");

    if ( a == b); {

        NSLog(@" a is equal to b");
    }

    else  NSLog (@ " a is not equal to b");

    BOOL z = ( a == b);
    if (!z) NSLog(@ " a is not (equal to b)");
    BOOL y = ( a > b);
    if ( y != YES) NSLog(@ " a is NOT ( greater than b");
    return 0;
    }
}**
```

I'm getting the error at the else statement, says expected expression.
What am I doing wrong here? What am I missing ?
Using xcode Version 8.2.1

Comment: copying over your code, it already gave warning on Xcode. first in your nslog you have a space between @<space>" which shouldn't have. second you already terminated the if condition before putting indicating an if-else-block.

Comment: You have a misplaced semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

The problem code is here:

```
if ( a == b); {

    NSLog(@" a is equal to b");
}

else  NSLog (@ " a is not equal to b");
```

The first line is equivalent to

```
if ( a == b) {} {
```

because the semicolon (`;`) is a null-statement.  This turns the `if ()` into a single-statement conditional.  The opening brace which follows is no longer part of the `if ()` statement, and is starting a new, independent, block.

This leaves the `else { ... }` which follows to not be part of an `if ()` statement, and thus is invalid.